# How to create in css concave border element

Tags: css, border, border-layout, border-radius

I want to create this layout of a box, but I am not sure is possible to make a concave border in the middle of the top border. Also, is possible to put a circle element with CSS?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an element with that cutout at the top by using [svg shapes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html). You can either create a vector image in a vector program and export this to SVG, then use the code, or find a suitable svg generator tool online.

A circle shape can also be added either by using svg shapes or by giving a border radius to an HTML box element via css.